# Yii framework : Display value from relation table in admin form

Tags: php, yii

I have a admin.php created by gii, inside it there's a table column 'lang_id' have relation to primary key 'id' of table 'lang'.

What should I put in the columns array ? I think i should use "Lang.name" but it didn't work.

protect/view/mainmenu/admin.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'mainmenu-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'menu_id',
        'Lang.name',   // I want this column display the name of Language, instead of lang_id
        'name',
        'remark',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}'
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

---

protect/model/Mainmenu.php

```
public function relations(){
    return array(
        'lang'=>array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Lang', 'lang_id')
    );
}

public function search(){
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id,true);
    $criteria->compare('menu_id',$this->menu_id);
    $criteria->compare('lang_id',$this->lang_id);
    $criteria->compare('name',$this->name,true);
    $criteria->compare('sorting',$this->sorting);
    $criteria->compare('remark',$this->remark,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the relation name is `lang`. Whereas in the columns array you have used `Lang` (with l in uppercase).
 So you will have to do this

```
'lang.name'
```

in the columns array

**and second thing** in the **search()**

You need to add one more line

```
$criteria->with = array(
'lang'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can work

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'mainmenu-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'menu_id',
        array(
            'name'=>'Lang',
            'value'=>'$data->lang->name',
        ),
        'name',
        'remark',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{update}'
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```